# How to build and include a 3rd party C library in Xcode 6.0

Tags: xcode, swift, ios8, xcode6, static-libraries

I'm trying to build a **3rd party C library** and include it in my project. The library is the Swiss Ephemeris and I'm trying to use the preconfigured Xcode project here https://github.com/dwlnetnl/SwissEphemeris.

I can get the framework to build properly, but I don't know how to include it in my project. Ideally, I want to **store the framework within the project** so that I can commit it to a repository and have developers check out the file, and build the project without the need to have the framework installed locally first. I'm not sure if that's possible?

So, if someone can explain:

- How to include the built framework into my project
- How to 'embed' it
  within the project so that the framework can be stored within the
  project.

it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static libraries are unsupported in Swift 1. You can use Objective-C to call the library.

Comment: The Swiss Ephemeris programmer documentation contains an example program. To import the framework use `@import SwissEphemeris;`, as any other framework. To link the static library please consult the Xcode documentation about linking frameworks and libraries.